# MySQL query with array values

Tags: mysql

i'm using this simple query right now:

```
SELECT * FROM ships ORDER BY shipid ASC
```

Now i have an array of shipids which should be searched...

```
$shipid = array("1","9","19","73");
```

Is there a way to easily do **ONE** query without loops nor building a query string?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipid=(IS IN ARRAY shipids) ORDER BY shipid ASC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do note that, assuming the array comes from user input, you've got yourself an SQL injection vulnerability if you just merge the array into the SQL string. You'd better sanitize, or rather parameterize, the array.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `IN` clause

```
SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipid IN (1,9,19,73) ORDER BY shipid ASC
```

You can create query string like below

```
<?php
$ships = array("1","9","19","73");
$query = "SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipid IN (".implode(',',$ships).") ORDER BY shipid ASC";
?>
```

Here is how it generates query string

**Script**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php
$ships = array("1","9","19","73");
$query = "SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipid IN (".implode(',',$ships).") ORDER BY shipid ASC";
print $query.PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipid IN (1,9,19,73) ORDER BY shipid ASC
```

Comment: Does this work in this way? SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipid IN (**shipids**) ORDER BY shipid ASC

Answer (score 2):

Try php `implode()` function to convert the array into string like:

```
$ships = implode(",", ships);
```

and use it like:

```
"SELECT * FROM ships WHERE shipid IN (".$ships.") ORDER BY shipid ASC"
```